# how to import huge tsv file into h2 in memory database with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have a huge `tsv` files and I need to import them into my h2 in memory database.

I can read it with `Scanner` and import it line by line but it takes for hours !

is there any faster way to import tsv file into h2 in memory database ?

Comment: I managed to read file and do not keep them into ram but still it takes too long

Comment: How many columns and rows does your file have, the one that takes hours to import? Asking so that I can recreate the issue first

Answer (score 3):

Use `insert into select convert` for direct importing from file into your h2 table.

[How to read CSV file into H2 database](http://makble.com/how-to-read-csv-file-into-h2-database) :

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "", "");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    stmt.execute("drop table if exists csvdata");
    stmt.execute("create table csvdata (id int primary key, name varchar(100), age int)");
    stmt.execute("insert into csvdata ( id, name, age )     select convert( \"id\",int ), \"name\", convert( \"age\", int)   from CSVREAD( 'c:\\tmp\\sample.csv', 'id,name,age', null ) ");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from csvdata");

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("id " + rs.getInt("id") + " name " + rs.getString("name") + " age " + rs.getInt("age") );
    }
    stmt.close();
}
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('test.csv');
-- Read a file containing the columns ID, NAME with
SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('test2.csv', 'ID|NAME', 'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=|');
SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('data/test.csv', null, 'rowSeparator=;');
-- Read a tab-separated file
SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('data/test.tsv', null, 'rowSeparator=' || CHAR(9));
SELECT "Last Name" FROM CSVREAD('address.csv');
SELECT "Last Name" FROM CSVREAD('classpath:/org/acme/data/address.csv');
```

[h2 csvread function](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvread)

**NOTE:** You can specify file's field separator for these commands.

Comment: Import huge `tsv` file, not `csv` file.

Comment: You can specify field separator using `fieldSeparator`, as I know csv is comma separated and tsv is tab separated.